# Is Pearson's chi-squared appropriate for models with low deviance explained?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, glmnet, deviance

I'm working on fitting a binomial GLM using LASSO in R (package glmnet). My response variable is a proportion which is generated using count data (successes and failures). The main purpose of my model is to determine which covariates make the best predictors of the proportional response variable, with the understanding that my response variable is affected by many different processes and not all of them are represented by the limited set of covariates that I'm using.

Depending on the parameters I use (which of the correlated variables I remove or keep, which lambda value I choose for LASSO, etc.) the deviance explained (`model$dev.ratio`) is between 25% and 35%. I know these values aren't huge, but they're about what I expected based on what I know about my response variable.

My question is: what's the best way to do model validation? **Is Pearson's chi-squared appropriate in this scenario to determine if the GLM is performing equally well on the original training data and a separate holdout data set?** Since the model only explains about a third of the signal in the training data, is it a near-guarantee that Pearson's chi-squared test will give a low p-value, indicating statistical significance between the model predictions and the holdout data? Or am I misinterpreting these two metrics? I'm unable to think of a situation where a model that captures 30% of the pattern is able to make predictions that are so close to reality that the predictions and actual measurements would be statistically *insignificant*.

If that's correct, is there a different metric (aside from Pearson's chi-squared) I can use to determine whether my GLM performs similarly on both the training data and the testing data? If both the training set and the test set have similar values for deviance explained, would that indicate similar performance on both sets of data?

Comment: Could you explain how you are applying a chi-squared test in this situation?  It would also help to clarify what you mean by "the predictions from my model originate from a different distribution than the actual values of my test set of data."  That seems to be telling us you think you are using the wrong model, but you haven't given us any information to assess that.

Comment: How do you calculate the explained deviance? Is it McFadden's $R^2$ that compares the log-likelihood of the model to the log-likelihood of a null model the predicts the prior probabilities every time? If so, I have read reports of McFadden himself saying that $0.2$$-$$0.4$ should be regarded as *very* high (though I have struggled to find the original reference).

Comment: @Dave I'm using the function built in to the glmnet package. More info on that here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117732/exact-definition-of-deviance-measure-in-glmnet-package-with-crossvalidation. I believe this is different than McFaddens - but please correct me if you think otherwise.

Comment: @whuber - I was going to use the chi-squared test to compare predictions from my GLM to a set of testing data that I removed before fitting the model. It's my understanding that Pearson's chi-squared will test whether the predictions and actual response variable are statistically different (i.e. come from different distributions).

Comment: If your calculation is different from McFadden's $R^2$, then how do you figure that you should express the result in terms of a percentage of something being explained? // One of the comments in the link (Jo Wmann Oct 3, 2014 at 10:59) sure makes it sound like some kind of McFadden-style calculation. // This sounds like a major XY problem where you have problem X that you think you can solve using Y, and then when Y leads to questions, you ask about Y instead of X. What is your X, feature selection?

Comment: @Dave Fair enough...My X would be model validation. I'd like to know if my GLM is performing equally well on the original training data and the holdout (testing) data. I'm trying to determine whether Pearson's chi-squared is appropriate for that - my thought was that it would not work in this situation, for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: Please edit that information into the original question.

Comment: The (legitimate) main question `My question is: what's the best way to do model validation? Is Pearson's chi-squared appropriate in this scenario to determine if the GLM is performing equally well on the original training data and a separate holdout data set?` now seems quite inconsistent with the title `Is Pearson's chi-squared appropriate for models with low deviance explained?`. Perhaps you could edit the title, or do you have an idea of why these are related?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147230/discussion-between-pfadenhw-and-dave).